# jQuery, how to nest HTML tags when creating an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I am working on a fancy expander thing that pops up when images are clicked - think the thing that pops up when you click on a google image search result (I didn't write the bulk of the code), and it is set up like this for each element:

```
<a  href="http://i.local.dev:5000/EW3GugE.jpg" 
    data-largesrc="http://i.local.dev:5000/EW3GugE.jpg" 
    data-title="http://i.local.dev:5000/EW3GugE.jpg"/>
<div class = "thumbcontainer">               
    <img src="http://local.dev:5000/thumbs/EW3GugE.jpg" />
</div>
```

The "data-title" attribute is evaluated by the javascript, and the jQuery code creates elements like this, taking the text that was in the title attribute and putting it inside a textarea, then appending it to the popup:

```
this.$title = $( '<textarea></textarea>' );

this.$details = $('<div class="og-details"></div>').append(this.$title, 
                                                  this.$description, this.$href);
this.$details = $('<div class="og-details"></div>').append(this.$title, 
                                                  this.$description, this.$href);
```

This is working fine, it puts the text in the textbox. But what I need to do is make some BBCODE/assorted other markup links, similar to:

[IMG]http://i.imgur.com/5VbkHIP.jpg[/IMG]

Didn't think this would work, but I tried:

```
this.$title = $('<textarea>[IMG][IMG]</textarea>');
```

It didn't work. Is there a way I can specify the text go in between those image tags? Should I be evaluating them as strings and just combining them or is this a bad way to do it?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the textarea's value using this code?

```
this.$title.val('[IMG][/IMG]');
```

Good luck. :)

Comment: Not working - now all that is in the text box is the [IMG][/IMG], the link isn't in between them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "this.$href" is the jquery object of the HTML

```
<a href="http://i.local.dev:5000/EW3GugE.jpg" data-largesrc="http://i.local.dev:5000/EW3GugE.jpg" data-title="http://i.local.dev:5000/EW3GugE.jpg"/>
```

I would try to directly modify the attribute "data-title" value, prior to the construction the $details object, so that the title text would be wrapped in between "[IMG]" tags. So, it would look like,

```
var myText = this.$href.attr("data-title");
this.$href.attr("data-title", "[IMG]" + myText + "[/IMG]");
```

Then, do

```
this.$details = $( '<div class="og-details"></div>' ).append( this.$title, this.$description, this.$href );
```